# Using pointer to class method as argument to the function, but as a function pointer, not pointer to the method

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I ran into the following problem. I have a class:

```
class My_Class
{
    public:
    My_Class(void);  // constructor
    double * Return_Values(double x, double y);  // returns a pointer to the array
}
```

I also have another class that I want (and need for some reason) to keep completely independent from class `My_Class`, but that has a method that needs a function similar to `My_Class::Return_Values(double x, double y)`. So I decided to try to pass a function pointer:

```
class Independent_Class
{
    public:
    Independent_Class(); // constructor
    void Crazy_Method(int a, int b, double * (*FunctionToOperate)(double,double));
}
```

Now I do the following in the main body of the code:

```
double * (My_Class::*pt2Member)(double,double) = NULL;                
pt2Member = &My_Class::Return_Values;
Fields = (My_Class_instance.*pt2Member)(0.0,0.0); // this works perfectly
```

Now I try to cheat a bit (yeah, I know function pointers are not the same as pointers to class members, but I still tried).

```
double * (*func)(double,double);
func=pt2Member;     // Doesn't work
Independent_Class_instance.Crazy_Method(1,1, &(My_Class_instance.*pt2Member))  //Doesn't work
```

So the idea didn't work. What is wrong? Can I somehow do what I want (keeping the classes independent)?

Answer (score 4):

You need to bind a pointer to the object. I'd recommend using `std::function` and `std::bind`. That will lead to much cleaner code unless for some reason you absolutely have to use raw function pointers.

Here's an example. This is going off memory so it may not be exactly correct, but it does show you how simple things are with `std::function`. Note that this was added to the standard library in C++11. If you have a really old compiler (even GCC 4.4 supports functional), you will need to use Boost. In which case, just replace all the `std`s with `boost`s below.

```
#include <functional>

class Independent_Class
{
    public:
    Independent_Class(); // constructor
    void Crazy_Method(int a, int b, std::function<double* (double,double)> FunctionToOperate);
}


std::function<double* (double, double)> func; 
func = std::bind(&My_Class::Return_Values, My_Class_instance, _1, _2);
Independent_Class_instance.Crazy_Method(1,1,func);
```

Comment: Doesn't work on my Mac. I installed gcc-46, the #include <functional> works perfectly, but later on std::function raises the error : std doesn't have member function. Do I need to install something else? Seems like not a good solution for me as I would like to have the code as general as possible and as independent of external libraries as possible

Comment: @user You also have to enable the `-std=c++0x` compiler option.

Answer (score 2):

A class's method takes an implicit argument that represents the pointer to the object that is invoking that method. Ie, the method

```
void MyClass::foo(int, int);
```

is actually

```
void foo(MyClass*, int, int)
```

This conversion occurs seamlessly in the compiler, though you can often see the effects with a debugger. It's how the `this` pointer exists, after all.

Because the method is implicitly expecting a pointer argument that represents the object, you can't just use a regular function pointer.